# Why is my bevel modifier only working on some edges?

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I want all my hard edges to be buttery smooth, but this object is just 1 object, and yet the bevel is applied in a weird way:

[image]

Is there a way I can "fuse" this object more so that it all acts as one and this bevel works properly?

Updated with Wireframe:

[image]

Updated with wireframe and no bevel modifier:

[image]

Comment: A wireframe would help more.

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @HaskellMcRavin Added wireframe!

Comment: @moonboots I'm sorry it's a proprietary client file I can't share

Comment: can't you share just the small part with the problem?

Comment: I can't tell what the geometry is like without the the bevel.

Comment: @HaskellMcRavin Added another wireframe

Comment: @a_good_swan then we can't help sorry. we can only guess the problem & solution. i'll make a guess, go into solid mode and tick *Face Orientation* under the *Overlays*. is it all blue? if not then select all with `A` and press `Shift+N` to recalculate normals. then also do `A` then `M` > *Merge By Distance*